# how to display and hide a form field according to select another field of form?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form

I use wordpress, contact form 7,

```
<p>Contact: [checkbox checkbox-932 "email" "Other"]</p>

<p>Other: [text text-327 placeholder]</p>
```

and I want to display other only when user check other option. Can you do that?

Comment: Yes, you will need to use JavaScript. Give it a shot and if you have trouble update your question with what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written the following code in the page where my contact form will be displayed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#moreinfo').hide();
    $('#more input').change(function(){
        if(this.checked)
            $('#moreinfo').show();
        else
            $('#moreinfo').hide();

    });
});
```

And the fields i need to display, i have put them in a div like this in contact-form-7 forms builder page, where you need to define the fields using shortcodes;

```
    <div class="form-group"> 
        [checkbox more id:more "Help us to know your requirements better"]</div>
        <div id="moreinfo">
        <div class="row">
<div class="form-group col-sm-6"> 
Property Requirement [select property_required class:form-control "Immediate" "15 Days" "1 Month" "6 Months" "1 Year"] 
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Don't forget to give the `id` to the checkbox field.

Comment: Thanks for your answer....

Comment: This works perfectly with wordpress :)

Comment: If this solution is working for you, cool. Just make sure you add lines that toggle the "aria-hidden" attribute, "false" if the element is visible and "true" if the element is hidden". Otherwise things like screen readers will still tell the user these fields are there.

Answer (score 1):

As doublesharp pointed out, this is something that is accomplished via JavaScript.

Given this HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkEmail" name="contact" value="email">E-Mail<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="chkOther" name="contact" value="other">Other<br>
<input type="text" id="chkOtherText" name="OtherText">
```

You would use the following JavaScript:

```
var chkBox = document.getElementById("chkOther");
var chkBoxTxt = document.getElementById("chkOtherText");

chkBoxTxt.style.display = "none";
chkBoxTxt.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "true");

function toggleOtherText() {
    if (chkBox.checked == true) {
        chkBoxTxt.style.display = "block";
        chkBoxTxt.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "false");
    } else {
        chkBoxTxt.style.display = "none";
        chkBoxTxt.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "true");
    }
}

chkBox.addEventListener("click", toggleOtherText, false);
```

You will have to modify the script based on the output of the plugin though.

Comment: ok I'll try this.. Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome. Do not forget to enqueue the script in your function,php file using the wp_enqueue function.

Comment: It totally slipped my mind, but there is an extra step needed to deal with assisting technologies. If a visually-impaired user came to your form using a screen reader, the reader would still dictate the existence of that textbox to the user regardless of the checked state of the box. In order to avoid this, we use the aria-hidden attribute so we set it to true by default and then, if the user checks the "Other" box, the text field appears and the aria-hidden attribute is set to false.

Comment: ok, got it. Thanks! It works perfectly with the jsbin. but when I add it to wordpress, it doesn't work. any ideas why?

Comment: Did you add the script using the wp_enqueue_script() function? If so, add this line to the top of this script: alert('The Script has loaded'); This way you'll know the script is being loaded correctly.

Comment: no I didn't add any functions. ok sure.. Thanks! :)

Comment: That might be why then. All JavaScript needs to be loaded through the wp_enqueue() function in your functions.php file. This will also allow you to specify where you want the script to load in terms of the wp_head() or wp_footer() functions (note: always go with wp_footer unless the script needs to load earlier such as the case with Type Kit).

Comment: yes I guess.. Thanks for your support!